# <td> form submit button not working when img exists within another <td> elem of same row

Tags: php, html

I have a table row with a few columns of data. In one column there is a submit button which sets a few session variables and brings user to a new page.

However, when i add an  tag to another  element in the same row, the submit button stops working and just refreshes the current page. The correct session variables still get set once the button is clicked but no page change which i find really odd.

```
<?php 
            for($i=0;$i<sizeof($memberDetails);$i++){
                if($memberDetails[$i][6] == '28274')
                    $clubID  = "AM Online";
                elseif($memberDetails[$i][6] == '25930')
                    $clubID = "AM Dundalk";
                elseif($memberDetails[$i][6] == '25364')
                    $clubID = "AM Newry";

                if($memberDetails[$i][5] == 0){
                    $arrowImg = "img/arrow-yellow.png";
                }
                elseif($memberDetails[$i][5] == -1){
                    $arrowImg = "img/arrow-lightred.png";
                }
                elseif($memberDetails[$i][5] == -2){
                    $arrowImg = "img/arrow-red.png";
                }
                elseif($memberDetails[$i][5] < -2){
                    $arrowImg = "img/arrow-morered.png";
                }
                elseif($memberDetails[$i][5] == 1){
                    $arrowImg = "img/arrow-lightgreen.png";
                }
                elseif($memberDetails[$i][5] == 2){
                    $arrowImg = "img/arrow-green.png";
                }
                elseif($memberDetails[$i][5] > 2){
                    $arrowImg = "img/arrow-greenest.png";
                }

                print "<tr>";
                print "<td>".$memberDetails[$i][2]."</td>";
                print "<td>".$memberDetails[$i][1]."</td>";
                print "<td>".$memberDetails[$i][3]."</td>";
                print "<td>".$clubID."</td>";
                print "<td>".$memberDetails[$i][4]."</td>";
                print "<td>".$memberDetails[$i][8]."</td>";            
                print '<td><img src='.$arrowImg.'/></td>';
                print "<td><form action=\"\" method=\"post\">
                        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"email_btn_$i\" value=\"Email Member\">
                        </form></td>";
                print "</tr>";

            }

            for($i=0;$i<sizeof($memberDetails);$i++){
                if (isset($_POST['email_btn_'.$i])){
                    $_SESSION['member_id'] = $memberDetails[$i][0];
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $memberDetails[$i][3];
                   // echo $_SESSION['email'];
                    header("Location:memberdetails.php");
                }
            }
```

If i remove the `print '<td><img src='.$arrowImg.'/></td>';` line from the above, or even just the img tag fom the td itself, then the redirect works perfectly.

I've tried a number of different ways of writing the print statement but haven't had any luck.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to put doublequotes around arrowImg <img src="'.$arrowImg.'"/>

Comment: Absolutely. The image tag is not properly formed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `image src` needs be like this `echo '<table> <tr> <td><img src="'.$arrowImg.'"/></td>';`

Comment: this doesn't work i'm afraid, either way i do it the image prints out fine, but still no page redirect. I've also tried including the closing `</img>` tag aswell but no joy